# How to correctly write hosts file to redirect to ip with subdirectory

Tags: networking, server, localhost, hosts

Hello i'm not really new to linux, but i stumbled upon a problem when I copied website on `localhost/subdirectory`.

The homepage is runing normaly but the links redirect to root of the server i.e. `localhost/en/rest-of-the-link` and not `localhost/subdirectoryen/rest-of-the-link`.

How can I add ip with subdirectory in hosts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do can not be done from the hosts file. The hosts file is just to statically map IPs to hostnames. It has no say in what path HTML pages are loaded from.

If the html is using absolute links from the server root eg. `<a href="/en/rest-of-the-link">` you can just add a . at the start to fix the issue so that instead of taking you to `http://localhost/en/<rest-of-link>` you will go to `http://localhost/subdirectory/en/<rest-of-link>`

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is one of the option, but i changed root directory in php.ini allready :) so i don't have to go through all of my files